# Should there be a version of the "Informed" badge for reading the code of conduct?

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request, code-of-conduct

The new code of conduct is, in my opinion, skillfully worded and worth a read. So, it seems appropriate for there to be a badge awarding those who read it, much like the Informed badge.

Comment: I think I'd prefer that the CoC becomes mandatory reading to get the Informed badge instead.  Don't know how they want to work that into the tour though.

Comment: As a note, the downvotes here are not likely due to your question- I mean, it's a pretty decent question. You've got all you need here to be a good Meta question- But voting can be different here on Meta. On feature-requests, which this is, people will often vote on the idea itself. People seem to disagree with this idea, so... You'll get downvotes. But don't worry, downvotes here won't hurt your rep.

Comment: Thank you @Kendra for the clarification, my heart skipped a beat there! I intended on only using the discussion tag, but feature-request and badges were auto-added.

Comment: Another user added those, and honestly... Those are the right tags. :) Discussion does work as well for this one, but in the end, it's still a feature-request, even if you remove the tag for it.

Comment: This question has proven to be quite the learning opportunity.

Comment: @speedtsars I [edited in the feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/372160/2) because I felt that it was more appropriate.  If you really are looking for pure discussion, you can edit that tag out.  I'd also advise changing the wording of the post so that it's more open to discussion beyond whether a new badge should be added.

Comment: I think I will keep the question as-is and restore your tags

Comment: Only if it gets revoked once one of your comments are flagged and the flag is approved as violating the coc, requiring another read to get it back

Comment: also now asked on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313847/158100

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While badges *are* for encouraging behavior we want to see (mostly), I would argue that, in my opinion, badges for reading something are kinda pointless.

Mainly because we *can't be sure* that you've read it, just because you scroll down. Any measure we take to ensure that you've read it... Well, it can be beat. Even a test at the end can be beat. And honestly, I'd argue it's not worth the effort. Either people will read the code or not, and if they don't... Either they follow it naturally or they butt heads with the mods and get linked to it again.

Honestly, I also find the "Informed" badge to be pointless, but there it is. I just don't see the point to adding another reading badge.

Comment: When it first came out, it was a nice and surprising easter egg.  So I suppose...I've proven your point...?

Comment: Badges may be pointless in proving, that someone actually did read the content, but absence of badges is a fairly reliable indicator, that someone *didn't* read the content.

Comment: @IInspectable Hmm... I hadn't thought of that. That's a very good counter argument, and a fair point. No badge = Yeah, pretty much almost guaranteed didn't read the content.

Answer (score 1):

## Badges Are Carrots

Badges, like dangling carrots, are an incentive.

An incentive is a thing that motivates or encourages someone to do something.

Bottom-line, we *should* be motivating or encouraging the reading of updated codes of conducts and badges fulfil this very function as does the announcement banner depicted in the following screen-shot:

[image: Announcement Banner]

Let's be less concerned with the meritocracy of badges and more concerned with the *function* of badges.

## Confirming Reading

Various tiers of (imperfect but no less sufficient) confirmations:

1. User hits code of conduct URL.
2. User scrolls to bottom of page.
3. User answers a singular random multiple choice question to demonstrate understanding.