# Why is the Code of Conduct Banner present on the Code of Conduct's page

Tags: bug, code-of-conduct

Is there a reason for the *Code of Conduct* Banner appearing when I'm in the *Code of Conduct* page ?

[image]

***Is that a technical issue*** or ***is that designed to work this way*** for any reason ?

Comment: As long as you didn't close that banner I see no problem in it being shown to you on all pages. Making  these banners disappear and reappear based on navigation context would also be confusing.

Comment: In my opinion thats an absolut nonsense to have an intrusive banner to point you on the page you are reading! Particulary for a site like SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Exchange uses *banners* to announce relevant new features that impact all users. The banners allow for rich content, including links to specific pages in or outside the network of sites. A banner can be dismissed at any time by the users by clicking the close element at the top right corner.

The code of conduct is a static content page that is served as part of the help system. As such it can't tell if *you've read the Code Of Conduct*. At best it could tell if the page was served to you. Only the about page has an active feedback function. If you scroll that page to the end you'll earn the [informed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) badge. Do know there is a request to add such *informed* badge for the CoC: [Should there be a version of the "Informed" badge for reading the code of conduct?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372160/should-there-be-a-version-of-the-informed-badge-for-reading-the-code-of-conduc)

Given that the banner system is an existing, multi-purpose, feature and that the Code of Conduct is not similar to the about page, there is no feedback loop between the page being shown to you and a banner that you haven't dismissed. As such, this is not a bug. The feature is not there.

I personally doubt if such feature is needed. I assume users are used to dismissing banners they no longer deem valuable for them. While there is some merit in dismissing a banner when a page related to the banner is shown I think it is confusing and counter intuitive if a banner disappears automagically. The few times this banner is used where it also links to a page is so seldom that I doubt it adds much value in the next 6 to 8 years.